# Linking with vulkan using GCC

Tags: c, linker, vulkan

I am not sure why gcc cannot find `vulkan.h`.

I explicitly told gcc where to look, but it still cannot find it

In my main.c I have

```
#include "vulkan.h"
int main(){}
```

compiling i get,

```
gcc main.c -L/usr/include -Ivulkan -lvulkan -o main
main.c:1:10: fatal error: vulkan.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "vulkan.h"
      |
```

I also know for a fact that vulkan.h is in `/usr/include/vulkan`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#define "vulkan.h"` or `#include "vulkan.h"`? What is the actual errors you get? Please [edit] your question to include both a [mre] as well as the full and complete build-log.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mistyped I meant #include "vulkan.h" I will edit the question to create the minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

> I explicitly told gcc where to look, but it still cannot find it. Here is the command -
>
> gcc main.c -L/usr/include -Ivulkan -lvulkan -o main

> I also know for a fact that vulkan.h is in /usr/include/vulkan

Option `-L` is for library linking, not for searching header files, for which there's `-I`; if you want to `#include "vulkan.h"`, here you have to use `-I/usr/include/vulkan`.